# How to write out the whole text from <p> elements inside a <span> element with python chrome webdriver?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using the python chrome webdriver to extract all the text from the description section of a geocaching website [(Here's a sample website if anyone wants to take a look)](https://www.geocaching.com/geocache/GC4ZJ9R). The text is stored in different <p> elements inside one <span> element.  I cannot figure out how to take all the <p> elements and save them as one string separated with spaces.

I tried using both of the solutions underneath, the first one only outputted the text from the first <p> element and the second one sometimes outputted the first one, sometimes more (but not all). I couldn't figure out why the second one is inconsistent with the number of elements.

```
desc_span = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/form[1]/main/div/div/div[2]/div[9]/span')
        p_elements = desc_span.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'p')
        desc = ' '.join(p_element.text for p_element in p_elements)
        print(desc)
```

```
desc_div = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/form[1]/main/div/div/div[2]/div[9]')
        all_elements = desc_div.find_elements(By.XPATH, '*') 
        desc = ' '.join(element.text for element in all_elements)
        print(desc)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, you should wait for visibility of all elements located by selector, and, probably, change selector.

Try code below:

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
p_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.UserSuppliedContent p')))
desc = ' '.join(p_element.text for p_element in p_elements)
print(desc)
```

Using your link (I am not logged in), output is `It's a "W" Thang. This is my first cache that I have submitted. Placed with permission. Magnetic` that corresponding all `p` tags in description section.
So, you're on right way, just need to wait until all elements are rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The desired texts are within `<p>` tags which have an ancestor `<div class="UserSuppliedContent">`

---

### Solution

To extract all the text from the description section of the [geocaching website](https://www.geocaching.com/geocache/GC4ZJ9R) and put into a list you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775808/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
driver.get(url='https://www.geocaching.com/geocache/GC4ZJ9R')
print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.UserSuppliedContent p")))])
```

Console Output:

```
['It\'s a "W" Thang. This is my first cache that I have submitted. Placed with permission.', 'Magnetic']
```

---

Further, if you want to take all the `<p>` elements and save them as one string separated with spaces you need to use [`join()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-join-method/) and you can use the following solution:

```
driver.get(url='https://www.geocaching.com/geocache/GC4ZJ9R')
print("".join(my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.UserSuppliedContent p")))))
```

Console Output:

```
It's a "W" Thang. This is my first cache that I have submitted. Placed with permission.Magnetic
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```